# What is the "pulley formula" and how to use it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string

In Newtonian Mechanics, I am learning a topic called 'Constraint Relations' and in it I've encountered several pulley constraints along with a general formula called "pulley formula"[image: Pulley Formula]

I am failing to understand it intuitively. Please teach me about it from scratch.

Comment: This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m6cP.jpg) may help.

Comment: What is the source of these formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "pulley formula" as you state is just a consequence of the fact that the string involved in the mass-pulley system is **inextensible** and it **never becomes slack**, i.e. its length cannot change.

To prove this, we shall observe the system from the inertial frame attached with the pulley. In this system, the velocity of $m_1$ is $(v_1 - v_p)\mathbf{\hat j}$ (where $\mathbf{\hat j}$ points in the vertically upward direction. And similarly the velocity of $m_2$ is $(v_2 - v_p)\mathbf{\hat j}$. Now since the length of the string is constant, the velocity with which $m_1$ is going up (or falling down) must be equal to the velocity with which $m_2$ falls (or comes up, respectively). Thus, this yields the following relation

$$(v_1-v_p) = - (v_2 - v_p)$$

Evaluating it, we get

$$\boxed{v_p = \frac{v_1+v_2}{2}}$$

Hence, we have derived the velocity relation. The acceleration relation can be quickly obtained by differentiating the velocity relation with respect to time.

**Note:** As stated explicitly above, the above relation is *only true* for strings with constant length, not extensible or "real strings". The above formulae can also not be used in a case where an *inextensible* string *slacks*, because in doing that the length of the string has changed.

Also, do not make the mistake to assume that $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_p$ are independent variables. They are interdependent, thus the above equation.

Comment: So both m1 and m2 move upwards? Is this in the lab frame?

Comment: @nasu No, they don't. Both move in opposite directions.

Comment: Not according to your formulas and to the diagram in the OP. Unless the magnitude of vp is between the magnitudes of v1 and 2, both  relative velocities will  point in the same direction. And also, is vp=0 they will point in the same direction. How do you understand this?

Comment: @nasu I am talking about the direction of velocities not in the ground frame, rather in the pulley frame. Discussing them in pulley frame is more fruitful and clearer.

Comment: So in the pulley frame they have the same direction? This follows from your formulas, doesn't it? Take v1=5 m/s, v2=10 m/s and vp=2 m/s, for example. The two relative velocities will be 3 m/s and 10 /s, both in the positive y direction.

Comment: @nasu This feels like going in circles. In my first reply itself, I said that "both move in opposite directions", and in the second I specified that "I am talking about the direction of velocities...in the pulley frame". Moreover, $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_p$ aren't three independent variables. You cannot set them to any arbitrary value by yourself. In fact, the relation exists only because they are interdependent.

Comment: Yes, we are going in circles. I am not talking about what you say but what your formulas say. They obviously say that the two velocities are in the same direction. Can you give some example of actual velocities that are possible in your understanding of the problem?

Comment: @nasu Since you are explicitly asking for numbers, here they are: $v_1 = 3 \rm{ m/s}, v_2 = 5 \rm{ m/s}$. Note that now this **fixes** the value of $v_p$, which is $4 \rm{ m/s}$. In the pulley frame, $(v_1 - v_p) = -1\rm{ m/s}$ and $(v_2 - v_p) = 1\rm{ m/s}$. Both have opposite signs, indicating opposite directions.

Comment: The formula describes the velocity for an observer.. If the pulley is going VERY fast upwards, you will see both masses go upwards, although they are moving in opposite directions relative to each other (indeed, if vp=0 then v1=-v2 which is a relation always valid in the pulley frame of references). The two velocities, being connected by v1=2vp-v2, can APPEAR to an observer to be both in the same direction or not depending on how fast the pulley travels, but are always opposite (one goes up, one down) in the pulley frame of reference.. and it could not be different...

Comment: @JalfredP I suppose that's what I am saying as well.

Comment: @FakeMod Indeed, I was attempting to clarify even more (:

Comment: @FakeMod I recently saw a case in which both the masses were moving down and the pulley was moving up and I am facing trouble understanding that. Can such a case be possible according to you? And if the case is possible, please give me an example of it.

Comment: @Vijay No. Not as long as the string is inextensible and taut.